# Differential equation (Stationary Point)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the differential equation $$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y-2x^2+1=0$$, expressing y in terms of x.

Find the particular solution which has a stationary point on the positive x-axis. Sketch this particular solution.

My attempt,

$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=\frac{2x^2-1}{x}$

$\frac{dy}{\frac{dx}{x}}-\frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2}$

$\frac{dy}{\frac{dx}{x}}+\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x})y=\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2}$

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y}{x})=\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2}$

$\int\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y}{x})dx=\int\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2}dx$

$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{1}{x}+2x+c_1$

$y=2x^2+c_1x+1$

How to proceed then?

Comment: Where? I put my integrating factor as $e^{\int -\frac{1}{x}dx}=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: In the second line of your attempt, while it is correct, it is customarily better to write as $$\frac 1x \frac{dy}{dx}-\frac 1{x^2}y=\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2},$$ which is a standard-form of a first-order linear differential equation.

Comment: You made mistake in the second line $1/x dy/dx \ne dy/(dx/x)$

Comment: HINT : The stationary point is ON the positive x-axis. You should have two equations in $c_1$ and $x$

Answer (score 1):

More like a comment.

$$
xy'-y-2x^2+1 = 0
$$
stationary point occurs when $y' = 0$ thus
$$
y_0 = 1-2x_0^2
$$
stationary point sits on the x axis (at least my interpretation) 
$$
y_0 = 0 = 1 - 2x_0^2 \implies x_0 = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
so we need
$$
(x_0,y_0) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right)
$$
thus plug these values into your ode solution for your constants.

Comment: I got the constant$=-2\sqrt{2}$. How to sketch the graph then?

Comment: I have not checked your solution (going off comments) check that. however, if it is a polynomial you can plot the solution as you would with any function $y = f(x)$.